# Possible conflict with multiple SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

We currently have a SSL certificate for mycompany.com in GoDaddy and they are asking me to get one for our QA department for the URL qa.mycompany.com. I have installed certificates just fine with Let's Encrypt before, but never for a subdomain, and specially with a domain with a certificate installed already.

qa.mycompany.com is hosted in another server, with another public IP. The DNS configuration is done in GoDaddy where mycompany.com and qa.mycompany.com is hosted. I am planning to use certbot to install Let's Encrypt certificate for qa.mycompany.com in QA server.

Is there any risk in doing this? Like overriding the SSL certificate of mycompany.com? Or making it invalid after installing the one for qa.mycompany.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "override" the certificates, especially if they're on different servers. They're generated and out there.

Your setup as you've described shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any risk in doing this? Like overriding the SSL certificate of mycompany.com? Or making it invalid after installing the one for qa.mycompany.com?

There is no risk or conflict with multiple SSL certificates. It is common to have multiple certificates or a single wildcard certificate. Wildcard certificate covers the root domain and all subdomains. For example, serverfault.com includes a wildcard certificate.

When a subdomain is hosted in another server, it is normal to get a separate SSL certificate for that subdomain.